# How to specify int8/int16 in Python

Tags: python

Int type is int32 or int64 in default in Python3.
How can we specify int8/int16 when declaring variable?
It is not possible in Python?
It is waste of memory if the int object is small and int8/int16 cannot be specified.

Comment: Native Python integers can be any size (limited by the amount of memory that's available) — so the short answer is "you can't".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Afaik python chooses the type according to the size of the number and there is no way of specifying which type of int you want python to use. If you are concerned about the waste of memory, python may not be the correct choice in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

Python doesn't have any built-in support for 8 or 16-bit integers. NumPy, on the other hand, does support the sizes you're looking for:

```py
import numpy as np
print(np.uint8(22))
```

Comment: Just a note, an instance of a single `np.uint8` value is actually larger than an `int` value, so this isn't useful for saving memory.

Comment: This doesn't make python use `int8` though, does it?

Comment: Huh, that's interesting. Why is that the case?

Comment: @Einliterflasche No, because Python does not have built-in support for explicitly declaring the size of an integer to be 8 bits.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark A python object is not simply the value, there is also other data associated with python objects. An `int` will be 24 bytes while `np.uint8` is 25 bytes. (Although this is at 0, an int will actually go up to 28 bytes at a small nonzero value). Numpy of course also has arrays, which will only require one additional byte for each new `np.uint8` value added, but a larger base size.